# update data with ng-include and ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

is it possible To update information using ng-click with ng-include ?

i have those following code
index.html:

```
<div layout-padding="" ng-include src="'form.html'"></div>
<div ng-controller="formCtrl" flex="" ng-click="changInfo()" md-ink-ripple>
```

form.html:

```
<md-input-container flex="" class="md-block">
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea ng-disabled="role || !user.isFlight" ng-model="form.descIsFlight" columns="1" md-maxlength="150"></textarea>
  </md-input-container>
```

formCtrl.coffee:

```
$scope.form =
      descIsFlight: "Boeing 747"
$scope.changeInfo = () ->
    $scope.form =
        descIsFlight: "Aibrus A320"
```

My goal are to remplace the content of the form with the new description `Airbus A320` (exmaple reloading the page).

is it possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define $scope.form in a controller that has parent scope over the ng-include and ng-click dom element